# Why doesn't file_get_contents() appear to have the same access as curl_exec()?

Tags: php

I am downloading favicons using PHP and I spent a while troubleshooting before I noticed that `curl_exec` appears to work for some sites while `file_get_contents` does not.

For example here is the response from `http://www.hellmanns.com/favicon.ico`

**file_get_contents**

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://hellmanns.com/favicon.ico): failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in
>   /home/arcmarks/public_html/arcmarks/source/class.FaviconFinder.php on
>   line 44

**curl_exec**

> h(
>   e?Câ¬^ÏÉÌŒ$   B#(ÌlcYfƒy9C¥D;üès¨H8§¥§‹&5é¨QÛœJ©O5Öžfå§LíáÛÜß¸n   Ü®Œa~   †}…l
>   “‘±“o}þþþ¥FHòòÞïïï/Á±mžç¿~L"-‚y¾i'öáÌ³²¶£A%«§¬?ùíÜ©„i­²~Âh*®^?ÖáµÅÅ™ØezU[¢<4¡-5;/ïÀöæØaéìÐÌ†cN
>   ,;U@Nã½§õðî‰Õ¨îÑ¹k_jÖšmîÙÌáÜÝ[æ™-ì·D¡?-s­wE‹# õ¹„$0”6&ï²1Ú¦Žž#”+$§HR¢@3€,3Â@üÿÿþÿÿP:H€ô¯VüáBâ™?„j
>   W~±¦ª†ôòóaQ   ŸE7Ç|@F2?G2?åóãäå¸~Q
>   p,KEv(Cud).#lUH4mkr$gj[ahVf9&2Se/@ZLwPYiF0qOG?y>QbJx+cIMDzW!-]*'t5B;<^%T6
>   _XsR=`   :n"A7831o N ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ€Àÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl_exec is based upon and entire project that is used in many different languages see here:

[Why doesn't file_get_contents() appear to have the same access as curl_exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355055/why-doesnt-file-get-contents-appear-to-have-the-same-access-as-curl-exec)

Hence it has much more support.

Answer (score 0):

The `403`response error indicates that the server rejected the request made by file_get_contents.

Curl and file_get_contents do not make the same HTTP request.

At a minimum CURL will use a different user-agent Header.

In general CURL is superior and faster than using file_get_contents for loading remote files.